# SKScene in SceneKit

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I am attempting to add an animated SKScene to SCNScene inside ARKit. Upon viewing [WWDC 2017 session 609](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/609/) this seems possible. In the presentation the code looks like this...

```
//Get SpriteKit scene
let spriteKitScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "SpriteKitScene")

//Create plane geometry
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)

//Set SpriteKit scene on the plane's material
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene

//If material double-sided, SpriteKit scene will show up on both sides of the plane
plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

//Create a SceneKit node for the plane
let sceneKitNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

//Add the Scenekit node to the SceneKit scene
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sceneKitNode)
```

Things I *can* do:

- Get the SKScene loaded
- Add sprites in sceneDidLoad() in the associated .swift file

Things I *can't* do:

- Use any of the traditional methods in the SKScene's .swift file, like didMove(to) or update().
- Add actions to nodes in the scene in sceneDidLoad()

Not sure what I am missing. The presenter in the season shows animated and interactive SK content.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

didMove doesn't get called because it isn't in the responder chain when added to diffuse.contents.

update was not being called because the SKScene is paused when adding it this way.